# PHP flushing output as soon as you call echo

Tags: php, windows, flush

I thought `flush();` would work, at least from what Google/Stackoverflow tell me, but on my Windows WAMP (Windows, Apache, MySQL, PHP) system it doesn't work.

Is there some PHP setting I have to set to make flush() work?

Here's my code:

```
<?php
echo "Fun";

flush();

sleep(5);

echo "<br>Mo";
?>
```

The code just outputs all together when the script is done executing (after 5 seconds).. I don't want this, I want 'Fun' to show up right away, and then after 5 seconds 'Mo'.

I've tried other combinations of flush like `ob_end_flush();` `or ob_implicit_flush(true);` but nothing is working. Any ideas?

Comment: did you check php.ini setting of implicit_flush?

Comment: @stillstanding, Yes I've turned that On and also tried setting `ini_set('implicit_flush', true);` ... still not working... i'm starting to think it has something to do with a bug on windows.

Comment: zlib.output_compression will also activate buffering if it's on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The script works fine from CLI, displaying "Fun", waiting 5 secs before displaying "<br>Mo".

For a browser the results might be a bit different because:

1. The browser wont start rendering right away. Getting 3 bytes of data for HTML document isn't enough to do anything, so it'll most likely wait for a few more.
2. Implicit IO buffering on the lib level will most likely be active until a newline is received.

To work around 1) use text/plain content type for your test; 2) needs newlines, so do an `echo "Fun\n";` and `echo "<br>Mo\n";` Of course you wont be using text/plain for real HTML data.

Comment: Yeah, I like your answer. Also can be client-side. :-)

Comment: You're right... I've been using Chrome all this time and it wasn't working. Trying my initial example (even without newlines and text/plan output) on Firefox worked great... I wonder if there's a way to make this work cross-browser... +1 but you might want to take out the \n and text/plain stuff.

Answer (score 7):

So that's what I found out:

Flush would not work under Apache's mod_gzip or Nginx's gzip because, logically, it is gzipping the content, and to do that it must buffer content to gzip it. Any sort of web server gzipping would affect this. In short, at the server side, we need to disable gzip and decrease the fastcgi buffer size. So:

- In php.ini:

  . output_buffering = Off

  . zlib.output_compression = Off
- In nginx.conf:

  . gzip  off;

  . proxy_buffering  off;

Also have this lines at hand, specially if you don't have acces to php.ini:

- @ini_set('zlib.output_compression',0);
- @ini_set('implicit_flush',1);
- @ob_end_clean();
- set_time_limit(0);

Last, if you have it, coment the code bellow:

- ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
- ob_flush();

**PHP test code:**

```
ob_implicit_flush(1);

for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    echo $i;

    //this is for the buffer achieve the minimum size in order to flush data
    echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);

    sleep(1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using CGI/FastCGI, forget it! These don't implement flush. The Webserver might have it's own buffer.

You can disable all output buffering in PHP with following command:

```
ob_implicit_flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

If the problem persists, although you explicitly set

```
implicit_flush = yes
```

in your php.ini, you might also want to set

```
output_buffering = off
```

which did the trick in my case (after pulling my hair for 4+hrs)

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini for `output_buffering`.

Comment: output_buffering = On <-- that's what i have.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is Apache here, which also may have buffers...