# PHP Flush that works... even in Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, flush

Is it possible to echo each time the loop is executed? For example:

```
foreach(range(1,9) as $n){
    echo $n."\n";
    sleep(1);
}
```

Instead of printing everything when the loop is finished, I'd like to see it printing each result per time.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

FINAL SOLUTION

So that's what I found out:

Flush would not work under Apache's mod_gzip or Nginx's gzip because, logically, it is gzipping the content, and to do that it must buffer content to gzip it. Any sort of web server gzipping would affect this. In short, at the server side, we need to disable gzip and decrease the fastcgi buffer size. So:

- In php.ini:

  . output_buffering = Off

  . zlib.output_compression = Off
- In nginx.conf:

  . gzip  off;

  . proxy_buffering  off;

Also have this lines at hand, specially if you don't have acces to php.ini:

- @ini_set('zlib.output_compression',0);
- @ini_set('implicit_flush',1);
- @ob_end_clean();
- set_time_limit(0);

Last, if you have it, coment the code bellow:

- ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
- ob_flush();

**PHP test code:**

```
ob_implicit_flush(1);

for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    echo $i;

    //this is for the buffer achieve the minimum size in order to flush data
    echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);

    sleep(1);
}
```

Related:

- [php flush not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706525/php-flush-not-working/4978642#4978642)
- [How to flush output after each `echo` call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133209/how-to-flush-output-after-each-echo-call/4763130#4763130)
- [PHP flushing output as soon as you call echo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483035/php-flushing-output-as-soon-as-you-call-echo/4768650#4768650)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. And if anyone has issues with this, try restarting your server... (Hey, that's what worked for me. Dunno why.)

Comment: @Matt php and server settings don't apply until you restart

Comment: @TimoHuovinen I didn't change php.ini in my case, though.

Comment: @matt ok, that's weird then :)

Comment: "service nginx restart" restarts with the new nginx.conf, at least in CentOS ;-)

Comment: str_repeat() should be as large as the output_buffering value. If it's 4096 => `str_repeat(' ', 4096)."\n";` to be sure the content is sent.

Comment: I got some better results by using a mixture of the commands given above, but I have to ask if there are any commands/configurations that I have to use with apache (since I'm not using nginx).

Answer (score 50):

The easiest way to eliminate nginx's buffering is by emitting a header:

```
header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');
```

This eliminates both `proxy_buffering` and (if you have nginx >= 1.5.6), `fastcgi_buffering`. The fastcgi bit is crucial if you're using php-fpm. The header is also far more convenient to do on an as-needed basis.

[Docs on X-Accel-Buffering](http://wiki.nginx.org/X-accel#X-Accel-Buffering)
[Docs on fastcgi_buffering](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_buffering)

Comment: Great, this worked excellent for me. Using nginx 1.6.2 on Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks for this comment.

Comment: Thank you SO much! Wish I'd discovered it an hour ago. Simple, elegant single line solution :)

Comment: This is what did it for me.

Comment: I like this simple in-script solution, which overrides the conf files. I got this to work by using `set_time_limit(0)`, sending only this header, no content type header, followed by my echo'd HTML (or require_once()), followed by `ob_flush()`, and then `flush()`. I could then do my long task (an eCommerce task) and then output the rest of the HTML when done to close the page, which adds some Javascript that redirects the page immediately to their order receipt.

Comment: This did work for me, but it broke th webpagetest.org tests. What could go wrong here?

Comment: as opposed to the accepted solution above which didn't work, this one did. Thanks!

Answer (score 29):

Easy solution on nginx server:

```
fastcgi_keep_conn on; # < solution

proxy_buffering off;
gzip off;
```

Comment: I'd give +2 if I could. After trying every other solution, this is the one that worked.

Comment: Same, best answer here.

Comment: Great method. Also note that all three directives can be used in `http`, `server` or `location` contexts. So you can be very selective where it applies.

Comment: works on Laravel Valet editing  /usr/local/etc/nginx/valet/valet.conf

Answer (score 9):

I didn't want to have to turn off gzip for the whole server or a whole directory, just for a few scripts, in a few specific cases.

All you need is this before anything is echo'ed:

```
header('Content-Encoding: none;');
```

Then do the flush as normal:

```
ob_end_flush();
flush();
```

Nginx seems to pick up on the encoding having been turned off and doesn't gzip.

Comment: +1 for a PHP only solution (which can be easily enabled ad hoc). Note that  to make it work `header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');` was needed too.

Comment: This `header('Content-Encoding: none;');` worked for me. No need for `ob_end_flush()` or `flush()`, just make sure the output is big enough by using `echo str_repeat(' ', 1024*64);`

Answer (score 5):

You need to flush the php's buffer to the browser

```
foreach(range(1,9) as $n){
    echo $n."\n";
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

Comment: You may want to call @ob_flush() as well.

Comment: @RC: just curious, why do you need an '@' before ob_flush? I'd use: `if(ob_get_level() > 0) ob_flush();`

Comment: @Roger, do you use output buffering or have output compression enabled?

Comment: @meze, it suppresses an error that you will get if output buffering is not enabled.

Comment: @Petah: then `ob_get_level` will return 0, there's no need to do @-hacks.

Comment: @meze, personal preferences. Me I would turn all output buffering off in such a case `while (ob_get_level() > 0) ob_end_clean()`

Comment: @Roger, it sounds like you have output buffering issues. Are you on shared hosting? Do you have a demo page I can look at, and/or a phpinfo output.

Comment: @Petah, i have: output_buffering = Off AND zlib.output_compression = Off AND here you can see the phpini data: http://pastie.org/1536717

Answer (score 3):

I found that you can set:

```
header("Content-Encoding:identity");
```

in your php script to disable nginx gzipping without having to modify the `nginx.conf`

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by flushing the output buffer in the middle of the loop.

Example:

```
ob_start();
foreach(range(1,9) as $n){
    echo $n."\n";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
```

Note that your php.ini settings can affect whether this will work or not if you have zlib compression turned on

Comment: Not working here. It prints everything at the end of the loop execution.

Comment: Check your php.ini for the following:  output_buffering = Off  zlib.output_compression = Off   (Make sure those are both set this way)

Answer (score 1):

I had a gzip problem comming from my php-fpm engine.
this code is the only one working for me :

```
function myEchoFlush_init() {
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
    ini_set('output_buffering', 'Off');
    ini_set('output_handler', '');
    ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
    ob_implicit_flush(1);
    ob_end_clean();
    header('Content-Encoding: none;');

}

function myEchoFlush($str) {
    echo $str . str_repeat(' ', ini_get('output_buffering') * 4) . "<br>\n";
}
```

This is my test function : it checks max_execution_time :

```
public function timeOut($time = 1, $max = 0) {
    myEchoFlush_init();
    if ($max) ini_set('max_execution_time', $max);
    myEchoFlush("Starting infinite loop for $time seconds. It shouldn't exceed : " . (ini_get('max_execution_time')));
    $start = microtime(true);
    $lastTick = 1;
    while (true) {
        $tick = ceil(microtime(true) - $start);
        if ($tick > $lastTick) {
            myEchoFlush(microtime(true) - $start);
            $lastTick = $tick;
        }
        if ($tick > $time) break;
    }
    echo "OK";
}
```

Comment: Don't use sleep as it may not be counted in execution time

Comment: `myEchoFlush_init()` worked except I had to remove the header from it.

Answer (score 0):

**Combining PHP Flush/Streaming with gzip (AWS ALB, nginx only)**

My interest in PHP streaming support was to enable the browsers to fetch early/important assets early as to minimize the critical render path. Having to choose between either PHP streaming or gzip wasn't really an alternative. This used to be possible with Apache 2.2.x in the past, however it doesn't look like this is something that's being worked on for current versions.

I was able to get it to work with nginx behind an AWS Application Load Balancer using PHP 7.4 and Amazon Linux 2 (v3.3.x). Not saying it only works with the AWS stack, however the ALB sitting in front of nginx changes things and I didn't have a chance to test it with a directly exposed instance. So keep this in mind.

**nginx**

```
location ~ \.(php|phar)(/.*)?$ {
  
    # php-fpm config
    # [...]

    gzip            on;
    gzip_comp_level 4;
    gzip_proxied    any;
    gzip_vary       on;

    tcp_nodelay     on;
    tcp_nopush      off;
}
```

gzip_proxies & gzip_vary are the key parameters for gzipped streaming, the tcp_ parameters are to disable nginx buffering/waiting for 200ms (not sure if that's still a default nginx setting).

In my case I only needed to enable it for the php files, you should be able to move it higher into your server config.

**php.ini**

```
  output_buffering = Off
  zlib.output_compression = Off
  implicit_flush = Off
```

If you want to manually control when the buffer is sent to the server/browser, set implicit_flush = Off and use ob_flush(); flush() and finally ob_end_flush().