# Send data with opened connection in PHP

Tags: php, connection, client

I'm trying to find a solution to my problem with sending data to client with PHP. The biggest issue is - what I'm trying to do is to keep sending data inside a single connection with PHP script. I'm sure there are other ways but currently I don't know how to solve this.

What I'm trying to do is: A client connects to a web server and keeps the connection opened, so the TCP connection is "established". He will keep making for example GET requests every X seconds to keep this connection alive.

Inside of this connection on certain event I want to send the client some data without him making the request! So it means the event is triggered on the server side, not on the client side.

There is no possibility of using any JavaScript or any client-side technique as my client is Arduino module. I can keep the connection opened but I need to pass data to the client by using HTTP.

I have a database set up on the server and PHP will send data to the client when something changes inside the database.

I was trying to play with php flush() running in loop in the PHP script; but that doesn't do it the way I want.

So any advices appreciated.
Thank you.

edit: would be perfect it the solution would also work on Windows machine!

edit2: There will be multiple clients, not just one (eg hundreds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I think I found the way I want it to work. The problem why flush() wasn't working is that I didn't reach the flush buffer limit before flushing. Also I'm using Nginx server and I disabled gzip (just in case).

My test code which absolutely works looks like this:

```
<?
ob_implicit_flush(1);

for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
  echo $i;

  //this is for the buffer achieve the minimum size in order to flush data
  echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);

  sleep(1);
}
?>
```

Found my answer here: [PHP Flush that works... even in Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870697/php-flush-that-works-even-in-nginx)

I will test it with my Arduinos if it can accept such output. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don’t have lots of clients, Server-side Events sounds like it could work for you. 
http://dsheiko.com/weblog/html5-and-server-sent-events

Just read that you will have hundreds of clients, in that case you probably won't want to use PHP but use node.js instead.

Comment: My clients will be Arduino modules, so no HTML5.

Comment: SSE is just HTTP without closing the connection. Creating a server/client is very simple. You’re running PHP on Arduino so you initiate the connection using PHP.

Comment: I'm not running PHP on Arduino. Arduino can do no such thing.

Comment: Ok, whatever software you’re running/writing on Arduino. It can surely make an HTTP request?

Comment: I must program it to do so. It's no web browser. It sends raw data and receives raw data, no logic. I must program it to print "GET / HTTP/1.1...." to ethernet port.

Comment: Sure. You’re going to have to do that regardless of whether you use SSE or not.

Comment: @paulgrav hundreds of open connections is usually not a problem for a server, problems start above the 10k mark ;)

Comment: @dualed Depends on how much memory you have installed on your server and how much memory is being consumed per process. If you have an 8GB box and each httpd/php process consumes ~20MB then you’re going to struggle to service more than 400 connections.

Comment: @paulgrav Never done anything with node.js, but I'm pretty sure it won't use much less memory. But if you need more you can always just put in more. And there is always swapping, might make things sluggish, but I'm pretty sure an Arduino won't notice...

Answer (score 0):

How about CRON jobs?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

I think that might be the solution for your project. If i undrestand CRON's correctly, what thy do is execute a given script at given intervals. So that is basicly what u want, scripts to execute for every X seconds. And inside your script u have your function working with the database.

Comment: Sorry I can't imagine doing it with cronjobs. I will have multiple clients - hundreds for example. With simply running script every second I can't determine which client on which port send the correct data. Or can I?

Comment: Im not en expert on this but i think that your script can have some sort of validation, of the ports and clients, if they have IDs or sth to identify themselves, and then when validation is complete the script send the appropriate data for the given client identification.

Comment: Just an idea, u could have the script send constant lets say 'pings' and after a client would receive this ping, he would send some data (his ID data whatever this is) and when the scrpit would receive that it would run validation on the data, and then send correctly and specificaly encrypted data to the correct client. And then he would decrypt and use the data for whatever u programm it to.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I will think about it if it is possible.

Comment: Could you further elaborate on how your Arduino data transfer works? What kind of data can it send, and what kind of data and in what form can it receive?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is IPC - Inter Process Communication. In your case I would suggest a message queue (or multiple of those)

(On the client)

1. Open connection to `foo.php`
2. When receiving a new line, process it.
3. If connection times out, re-open it

(On the server - `foo.php`)

1. Open a [Message Queue](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.sem.php) (You will have to register a message queue for each user!)
2. Register it so that your `bar.php` knows about it.
3. Start a [*blocking* receive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.msg-receive.php).
4. When a message is received, send whatever you want to send, FLUSH OUTPUT BUFFERS, go back to **2.**
5. If anything times out, back to **2.**

(On the server - `bar.php`)

1. When the database changes, send message to all active queues

There are a few problems with this approach:

- The server side only really works on Linux / Unix (that includes Macs)
- There is a limited number of message queues
- You may have to do some housekeeping, removing old queues, etc.

The benefits:

- This is application independent. Message queues are an operating system feature, thus your `bar.php` could really be say a java application.

Comment: Thanks for the response, looks very interesting. However I somehow managed to make it work more-less. I just had to disable gzip on my nginx server and flush wasn't working because I didn't reach the buffer size to make it flush. Now when I run the script I can see output flushing step by step...but there's this problem: my PHP server allows me to process only one script at a time. That means when I run one script in the loop, another client can't connect because php server won't run another script. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: @majodom Are you opening a session? Sessions on PHP are mutually exclusive, so this may be your problem.

Comment: No sessions. My current test script looks like this:
`ob_implicit_flush(1);$i=0;while(1){echo $i;echo str_repeat('',1024*64);sleep(1);$i++;}`
`

Comment: @majodom I don't see why this should prevent you from opening more than one connection, is it a limitation of your hoster?

Comment: No I've got all running on my computer. When this (or any other) script is running in a loop, I can't open any other PHP script from my browser.

Comment: @majodom This sounds very odd, there is definitely something wrong with your server setup

Comment: I googled and found out that it appears to be normal behavior: http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?3,198958
Unfortunately I'm not using PHPFPM and I don't use session.

Comment: @majodom maybe you should use apache instead I'm pretty sure it can handle multiple PHP instances at once

Comment: I found out it also works on nginx. It didn't work because I was trying to open the same script from the same browser - which would use the same connection with server, which is currently occupied by the former running script flushing its data.

Comment: @majodom it still should not lock up. You should consider switching to polling, you don't want to get into a dead lock with a few hundred clients