# How to disable PHP Phar - GZip Compression

Tags: gzip, phar, php

I am trying to show echo'd statements as a PHP script is running.

I have tried every variant of flushes I can find, I have turned on Output Buffering in my server's PHP settings (Linux) but I am just out of ideas!

I have read having `GZIP compression enabled` can be an issue.
Our server has the PHP Phar package installed.

I added `phar.readonly=1` to the `php.ini` with no luck it still shows `enabled` in `PHPinfo()`!

Comment: *"I have read having GZIP compression enabled can be an issue."*: I think they mean GZIP compression of the content which is transferred to the client. As far as I know it should not be enabled if you are not enabling it in your code. Something like `ob_start('ob_gzhandler');` would enable.

Comment: PHAR gzip compression has nothing to do with gzip compression in http responses.  If responses are being compressed, you'll need to disable it it Apache/nginx or whatever web server you are using.  Flushing output from PHP can still be buffered by the web server and not sent until PHP terminates.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5014771/892493)