# ob_flush () does not work on my server

Tags: php, apache, io, output-buffering

This function works perfectly on my other server and locally on my pc showing every second the numbers, but when I send the cloud code from my client it only shows the results after the page loads 100%.

It works correctly here:
http://kicklaunch.me/buffer.php

In this only when the page loads completely:
http://raio.adm.br/buffer.php

Both servers have the same PHP version 5.4.45

```
<?php
for($i=0; $i<20; $i++) { 
    echo 'printing...'."<p>";
    ob_flush(); 
    flush(); 
    sleep(1); 
}
?>
```

**SOLUTION**

output_buffering = Off

```
ob_implicit_flush(1);

for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    echo $i;
    //this is for the buffer achieve the minimum size in order to flush data
    echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481235/php-flush-ob-flush-not-working

Comment: This question did not solve my problem.

Comment: In production there likely is a proxy server and PHP is executed by another process via (F)CGI. The proxy may be configured to buffer the complete response before passing it on to the client.

Comment: You should never need to use "real" code like this, so just move on that it does not work and look into using queues, ajax, websockets, sse etc

Comment: @TobiasK How do I configure this?

Comment: Depends on the proxy/setup of course. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5014771/7362396 for an Nginx example. However Lawrence is correct, this is really bad practice and indicates a design issue.

Comment: Can you create a new file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it, and look for `output_buffering` value? Perhaps it may be turned off in your server.

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal no value

Comment: Are you on a shared hosting? or your own server? It seems like output_buffering is Off in your server. You need to edit your php.ini file and uncomment the `output_buffering = Off' option and set it to `output_buffering = On`or `output_buffering = 4096`

Comment: Post the solution that worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have mentioned that you don't see any value for `output_buffering` in your comment, I assume it's turned off in your server.

If you are using your own server, then look for the `Configuration File (php.ini) Path` option in your `phpinfo` page (which I asked you to create in comments).

Then open that file, find the `;output_buffering = Off` line, and change it to:

`output_buffering = 4096`

You might need to restart your apache server (or your web server if it's different).

=============================================================

If you are on a shared hosting, most hosting providers allow you add your own configurations by adding a `php.ini` file to your `public_html` folder.

Create a file named as `php.ini` and include `output_buffering = 4096` in it, then upload it to your `public_html` folder. It should work.

Hope it helps :) Feel free to ask anything if you have any doubts.