# nginx proxy_pass can't got full response data from outputstream

Tags: java, nginx, kubernetes

The backend endpoint works using k8s-client to watch POD logs with the following code.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{podName}/log", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void queryLog(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable(name = "podName", required = true) String podName,
                         @RequestParam(name = "container", required = true) String container,
                         @RequestParam(name = "tailLines", required = false) Integer tailLines,
                         @RequestParam(name = "timestamps", required = false) boolean timestamps,
                         @RequestParam(name = "follow", required = false) boolean follow) {
        try {
            PodLogs logs = new PodLogs();
            InputStream is = logs.streamNamespacedPodLog(namespace, podName, container, null, tailLines, timestamps, follow);
            copy(is, response.getOutputStream());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("exception", ex);
        }
    }

    public static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {

        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                String str = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                out.flush();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        }

    }
```

The front:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        
        var xhr = null;
        
         function setConnected(connected) {
                
                document.getElementById('connect').disabled = connected;
                document.getElementById('disconnect').disabled = !connected;
                document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = '';
            }
          
         function connect() {
        
          xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

          xhr.open('GET', `http://proxy.k8s.io/backend/api/pod-0/log?container=pod&tailLines=500&timestamps=true&follow=true`, true)

          xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            setConnected(true);
            if (xhr.readyState >= 3 && xhr.status === 200) {
               console.log("###")
               console.log(xhr.responseText)
               document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = document.getElementById('response').innerHTML + xhr.responseText;
            }
          }

          xhr.send()
        }
         function disconnect() {
                
                if(xhr != null) {
                    xhr.abort();
                }
                
                setConnected(false);
                console.log("Disconnected");
            }
        </script>
        
    </head>
    
    <body  onload="disconnect()">
     <div>
        <button id="connect" onclick="connect();">Connect</button>
        <button id="disconnect" disabled="disabled" onclick="disconnect();">Disconnect</button>
        </div>
    <div id="response"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I could get the full log and watched new generated log **without nginx**.
However nginx with the following config can't get the full log from backend.

```
upstream backend {
        server backend:8080;
        keepalive_timeout 60s;
        keepalive 60;
        keepalive_requests 100;
}

server {
    listen       80;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /backend/api/ {
        proxy_pass http://backend/;
    }
}
```

The expected log sample:

```
2021-08-02T02:51:04.857054753Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
2021-08-02T02:51:04.857057468Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
2021-08-02T02:51:04.857060467Z  at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
2021-08-02T02:51:04.857063232Z  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

The sample log I got:

```
2021-08-02T02:51:04.857054753Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
2021-08-02T02:51:04.857057468Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
2021-08-02T02:51:04.857060467Z  at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHt
```

It looks like that the last chunked data was lost.
When I accessed it with `tailLines=200`, some data still was lost. And when new logs were generated, no new data could display in the front page.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is the incorrect [proxy_http_version](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_http_version).
By default, the version 1.0 is used. Version 1.1 should be used for the keepalive connection.

Docs say:

> Syntax:   proxy_http_version 1.0 | 1.1;
> Default:
> proxy_http_version 1.0;
> Context:    http, server, location
> This directive appeared in version 1.1.4.

Sets the HTTP protocol version for proxying. **By default, version 1.0** is used. **Version 1.1 is recommended for use with keepalive connections** and NTLM authentication.

How to fix:
Add `proxy_http_version    1.1;` under location block.

```
    location /backend/api/ {
        proxy_http_version    1.1;
        proxy_pass http://backend/;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely due to flushing to output in each iteration, and Nginx only forwarding the first chunk.

This is in the specs:

> When buffering is disabled, the response is passed to a client synchronously, immediately as it is received. nginx will not try to read the whole response from the proxied server.

Try `proxy_buffering on;` in nginx, or the header `X-Accel-Buffering: yes`. Or buffer the whole response in Java.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/23171377/7362396